# Error when configuring TeamCity's Artifactory plugin

Tags: teamcity, artifactory

I have installed the Teamcity Artifactory plugin on my Teamcity 10 but when I configure the artifactory by providing the server URL and doing the Test Connection it gives below error:

```
Error occurred while requesting version information: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the TeamCity instance is unable to reach your Artifactory instance. 
Can you do a ping call from the TeamCity to Artifactory? Even better will be to run the [Artifactory REST API call for the system ping](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SystemHealthPing), using your defined URL of Artifactory in TeamCity.

The REST should look like that:

curl -u user:password "https://{artifactoryURL}:{port}/artifactory/api/system/ping"

After running this from TeamCity instance see if you are able to reach the Artifactory instance.

Also, do you have any proxy server between TeamCity to Artifactory? From the error it seems like there is a proxy server in the middle, if so please follow the instructions on how to configure the TeamCity Artifactory plugin to go via the proxy server [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/TeamCity+Artifactory+Plug-in#TeamCityArtifactoryPlug-in-ProxyConfiguration).

Comment: I added a SSL cert of artifactory from chrome security tab and imported in teamcity and its connecting now.

Comment: unfortunately I am facing the same error today again even though I have imported the certificate. the plugin says test connection successful but in build it gives certificate error. please suggest what to do

Comment: I can ping to artifactory server from the teamcity server.. still after importing the certificate I am getting error on building